# Performance with hash-and-range primary key: Dynamodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, loopbackjs

I am building an application using Node.js and loopback. A component of the application is storing login attempts into DynamoDB. I am very new to this DB and I am running into issues.

Currently, my hash key is an email and my range key is a unix-timestamp of the moment when a login attempt occurred. Essentially, I am need to get all of the data from the DB, to produce a list of the last login attempts. First thought was to use **scan**, however it does not allow the list to be ordered based on the lasted login attempt. The issue with using **query**, is that I have to access all the emails and not just items specific to one specific email. I would think I could make all the hash values the same, but then this will create performance issues down the road based on the way dynamoDB stores its data.

Has anyone else run into this type of problem and have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

A NoSQL database like Amazon DynamoDB works best by storing and retrieving data by a specific primary key ("Hash"). It is also possible to identify data by a primary key plus an additional value ("Hash and Range").

However, your requirement of wanting to know the "last login" does not lend itself well to a NoSQL database, since scanning through data is a very CPU- and IO-intensive.

An alternative should be to create one Item (record) per user, and store an Attribute (similar concept to a "Column") on that Item of the user's last login time. That way, you only need to retrieve one specific record to discover the last login time.

If you also wish to keep a full history of login attempts, this could be done on a separate Table, with a Hash and Range and one Item per login attempt. This would be separate from the above Table that has only one Item per user.

Comment: Thanks for all of the input, I should to take a different route by using secondary indexes and only query failed login attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You could try bucketizing your unix timestamps to benefit from DynamoDB's query functionality.

Example schema:

- hash key = date
- range key = timestamp
- other attribute = email

Example item:
{"date": "07/31/2015", "timestamp": 1438393927, "email": "abc@def.com"}

Using this schema, all login attempts within a specific day would be stored under the same hash key. You could efficiently query for recent logins by providing the current date as your hash key. You could even drill down further and have a hash key represent a single hour.

Example query:

- KeyConditions: {"date" = "01/01/2015"}
- ScanIndexForward: false  // most recent logins come first

Example result:

- {"date": "01/01/2015", "timestamp": 1420153200, "email": "abc@xyz.com"}
- {"date": "01/01/2015", "timestamp": 1420153199, "email": "def@xyz.com"}
- {"date": "01/01/2015", "timestamp": 1420153198, "email": "abc@xyz.com"}

**Pro**: evenly distributed data, scalable, good temporal locality for efficient time-based querying

**Con**: querying for login attempts over date ranges / buckets aren't as simple. ie, logins for the past 3 days would require 3 separate queries (one for each date)

**PS**: if your query patterns require both querying by date as well as email, use a global secondary index (GSI) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

Comment: Thanks! Due to these constraints, I ended up creating a secondary index and I only show failed login in attempts, which makes this process a lot easier!